# Saving file in specified directory Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs, writefile

I want to save an image using fs.writeFile, but I'm not able to do this.

The path in which i want to do this: C:\Users\poz\lotos\images\1232133123@gmail.com

My code:

```
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime() + ".jpeg";
    var dir = "C:/Users/poz/lotos/images/" + email;

    mkdirp(dir);

    var data = image.replace(/^data:image\/jpeg;base64,/,'');

    var dir2 = dir + "/";

    fs.writeFile(__dirname +'/../../images/' + email + '/' + n, data, 'base64' , function(err){
      if (err)
        return console.log(err);
    });
```

*The folder is created.

An error which I'm getting:

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\poz\lotos\images\1232133123@gmail.com\1602604489722.jpeg'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Users\poz\lotos\images\1232133123@gmail.com\1602604489722.jpeg'
}

Comment: try  `mkdirp.sync(dir)`

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon thanks man it's working. I thought it was fs.writeFile problem :P

Comment: FYI, it makes no sense to construct an absolute path in the `dir` variable, create that directory and then not use that same variable when constructing the file name.

Comment: On the beginning I tried to make everything by dir, but it didn't worked so I tried to fix it by myself by changing the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdirp(dir)
```

Returns a promise that is not awaited.

You should call

```
mkdirp.sync(dir)
```

Or rewrite your code in an async style.

I would suggest using:

```js
const savePath = require('path').join(__dirname, '/../../images/', email)
```

to avoid issue related to OS or missing trailing slash.